# system() call not working with ifup/ifdown

Tags: c++, debian

I am writing a C++ system supervision daemon for an embedded device running debian jessie. This daemon process needs to be able to reconfigure network devices. The daemon runs as root user and uses the calls system( "ifdown --force -v eth0" ) and system( "ifup --force -v eth0" ) to read in the changed interface definition. When I type these commands as root user in a shell I get the following output:

```
root@mds:/etc/network/interfaces.d# ifdown --force -v eth0
Reading directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth2
Configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-down.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/upstart
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/wpasupplicant

ip -4 addr flush dev eth0 label eth0
ip link set dev eth0 down
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-post-down.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/wpasupplicant

root@mds:/etc/network/interfaces.d# ifup --force -v eth0
Reading directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth2
Configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet)
run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
ip addr add 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255    dev eth0 label eth0
ip link set dev eth0   up

run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/mountnfs
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
```

But when I execute the same commands through the system() call in my daemon running in the same shell I only get this:

```
2017-07-10 17:25:16.591 +02:msg:MDSSV:15: executing ifdown command: ifdown --force -v eth0
Reading directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth2
2017-07-10 17:25:17.596 +02:msg:MDSSV:15: executing ifup command: ifup --force -v eth0
Reading directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1
Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth2
```

The eth0 device remains unchanged. It looks like ifup/ifdown read only the device configurations but do not do anything else. Why are ifup/ifdown behaving different when called through system()?

Comment: `system()` shouldn't exist (and shouldn't be used) IMO. Too many failure scenarios, too little control, too many possible security vulnerabilities. Better to use one of the `exec*()` system calls.

Comment: I have also used fork/exec with the same results.

Comment: Just in case somebody is still interested in this problem, I found a solution. It think that it was caused by the netplug daemon which was installed on the system. It seems that this daemon does not release the network devices when ifdown is called, therefore ifup didn't work and could not activate the new settings. I replaced netplug with ifplugd and now it works.